# How could I convert uint type to bytes type in solidity?

Tags: solidity, type-casting

I want to convert uint type data to bytes type in solidity. I've found a answer about this which is like below.

```
function toBytes(uint256 x) public pure returns (bytes memory b) {
    b = new bytes(32);
    assembly { mstore(add(b, 32), x) }
}
```

But this doesn't work like what I thought. For example, if I put `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abc` to the input value, I expected to have a return value which looks like this `0xabc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. But this function returns same as input value which is `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abc`. How could I convert `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abc` this to `0xabc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` this in solidity?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you are trying to achieve?  In your example byte boundaries are not preserved.  Original `uint` has bytes `0a` and `bc`, while resulting `bytes` has `ab` and `c0`.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov I meant if I put the uint256 input value `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abc` to a function, I want to receive `0xabc`.

Comment: `0xabc` is not a valid `bytes` value, as it is 12 bit long, while each byte is 8 bits.  So it is fractional number of bytes.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Oh OK, then I'll change my example to `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abcd`. I want to receive `0xabcd` when I give an input value `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abcd`. But that function returns same as input value.

Comment: But what would be correct output for the original example?  I need this to understand the general rule.

Comment: Perhaps you want to convert from little endian to big endian?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is called [bit shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). Solidity allows bit shifting using the `<<` and `>>` operators.

For your example, the non-zero portion of `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000abcd` is `abcd` which occupies 16 bits. Because a bytes32 is 256 bits long, you must shift 240 bits to return the desired value:

```
function toBytes(uint256 x) public pure returns (bytes32) {
    return bytes32(a) << 240;
}
```

Note that the above example only works when the initial value is 2 bytes long.  If you are not certain of the length of your initial value, you can determine it using a for loop and some division:

```
function toBytes(uint256 a) public pure returns (bytes32) {
    uint i;
    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        if (a / 256**i == 0) break;
    }
    return bytes32(a) << (32-i)*8;
}
```

#### Further reading:

- [Solidity documentation on bit operations](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/types.html#bit-operations)
- [Understanding the difference between bits and bytes](https://www.lifewire.com/the-difference-between-bits-and-bytes-816248)

Comment: OP wants to convert to `bytes` not to `bytes32`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```solidity
function toBytes(uint256 x) public pure returns (bytes memory b) {
  uint l = 32;

  if (x < 0x100000000000000000000000000000000) { x <<= 128; l -= 16; }
  if (x < 0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) { x <<= 64; l -= 8; }
  if (x < 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) { x <<= 32; l -= 4; }
  if (x < 0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) { x <<= 16; l -= 2; }
  if (x < 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) { x <<= 8; l -= 1; }
  if (x < 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) { x <<= 8; l -= 1; }

  b = new bytes (l);

  assembly { mstore(add(b, 32), x) }
}
```

For me it does:

```
0x0 -> 0x        (zero bytes)
0x1 -> 0x01      (1 byte)
0xFF -> 0xFF     (1 byte)
0x100 -> 0x0100  (2 bytes)
0xFFFF -> 0xFFFF (2 bytes)
etc.
```